# Moving a div inside a container from edge to edge

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a div (shapped like a bar) move inside of a container (infinite loop, back and forth).

You can find the codepen here: https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/wvzLRPW?editors=0010

I just can't seem to find the correct method to do so.

I used `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the position of the parent element and tried to tie the position of the bar to its parents left and right values, but that doesn't seem to work. It bobbles back and forth in the middle of nowhere.

Basically the intended results are that the bar moves from one edge to the other edge of its container element (but never leaves the container).

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have to do this with JavaScript, or would a simple CSS animation suffice?

Comment: ah yes, i forgot to mention... only javascript :)

Comment: Where did you get `(h >= 250)` from? What does 250 represent? Also, you have your `setInterval` running every 1 ms. Browsers actually can't go that fast. The minimum is 10.

Comment: The 250 is random, I just tried to mess around with values. And thank you.... I had no idea about the minimum value for setIntervals.

Comment: Is this for a course? This problem is so broad that StackOverflow probably won't be able to give you an answer. I would recommend talking to one of your instructors.

Comment: Nope, this is for me. I'm decent with JS I'm just not that good with animations.

Comment: Voting to close because the code is in an external link. Please use a stack snippet and a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: I've seen plenty of questions linking to external sites like codepen.

Comment: Nowhere in your code do I see you calculating how far you want the bar to move. You're just telling it to move a random amount. Start there. That's not a coding question — that's a conceptual question. Once you know what point information you need, you can create a JS variable for each point, and Google where in JS/the browser to find those points.

Comment: Take a look now, I added some code which 'should' work?

Comment: The problem is in your interval... it is overlapping the changes so that's why you can not see it. Also the boundary is 100px not 250px. Give it a try with 100 ms and you will get the right results.

Comment: @RizaKhan why only Javascript? This can be easily done with CSS.

Comment: @symlink, I suppose CSS could potentially work. I need to know the position of the element that is moving, but I suppose I can 'watch' for it inside of a setInterval

Answer (score 0):

This can very easily be achieved with pure CSS using `@keyframes` rule with an animation on the parent `bar`. ***CSS Animation will be smoother looking IMHO...***

But if you want to use JS...

You can create a *setInterval* with function that **add/remove** classes, then use a conditional to check if the class is set. If it is set, *increment/decrement* the **width** value of your nested element back and forth.

I use `element.clientWidth()` to get the width of the nested element and the width of the parent element, then subtract the nested elements width with the parent width to get the constraint for the back and forth.

Create a function, with a conditional, one that increments, the other that decrements the starting value of `0`. Use the conditional to check the class: `left` or `right`... If it is `left`, less than the constrained width, it runs the interval that increments the width value. Then an additional conditional that checks if it is equal to the width of the parent element and the width of the nested element, if so, remove the `left` class and add `right`. Then the other conditional checks if `right` is set as class and it basically reverses the `start` value to decrement back to `0`.

```js
let parent = document.getElementById('bar');
let inner = document.querySelector('#bar span');
let width = parent.clientWidth - inner.clientWidth;
let start = 0;

const moveIt = setInterval(move, 2);

function move() {
  if (inner.classList.contains('right')) {
    inner.style.left = `${start--}px`;
    if (start === 0) {
      inner.classList.remove('right');
      inner.className = 'left';
    }
  } else {
    inner.style.left = `${start++}px`;
    if (start === width) {
      inner.className = 'right';
      inner.classList.remove('left');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#bar {
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#bar span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 42px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0 12px #800000, 0 0 3px #3d3d3d;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <span class="left"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a CSS animation and don't worry about Javascript:

```css
.bar{
  border:solid 2px #333;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
}

.bar::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orangered;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  animation: slide 4s infinite linear;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {left: 0}
  50% {left: calc(100% - 40px)}
  100% {left: 0}
}
```

```html
<div class='bar'></div>
```